# Kendo UI grid - different templates for Edit and Create

Tags: kendo-ui

We are using Kendo UI grid to display some records. The requirements need us to have a column (Say "File Name")shown as a text box when the user clicks on "Edit". 
However, when user clicks on the "Create" button in the toolbar, the same column should be replaced with a File Select control which will allow the user to select a file from his machine. The other columns remain the same. 
I have already tried searching through Stack Overflow as well as the Kendo UI Grid forums, but to no avail.
Is there any way to achieve this? Any pointers will be of great help.

Regards,
Nikhil

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using different editor templates for create/edit is not supported. You need to use the [edit](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#edit) event of the Grid to change that text input to file input with JavaScript. To distinguish between edit and create you can use the isNew() method of the model.
i.e.

```
edit:function(e){
      if(e.model.isNew()){
          //replacement logic
      }
 }
```

Similar question is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393443/kendo-ui-how-to-make-specifc-fields-readonly-on-edit-while-on-create-its-edita).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will try this out and let you know if there is any issue(s).

Comment: I've created a workaround as e.model.id===''||e.model.id===null however your solution is clean